# How to recognize a plugin that is good for Vundle ? - Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, vundle

I'm in trouble with some plugins, I can't say if they are for Vundle or not, as a consequence I can't say if the problem is Vundle itself or not, most of the vim docs are horribly paginated, so I'm asking, there is a way to know for sure that a plugin is designed to run under Vundle ?

Comment: From my understanding (I don't use vundle) all plugins should work as long you know the github url (the end of it anyways).

Comment: @FDinoff I don't think so, they also have different building systems, the URL is for the package manager with `BundleInstall`

Comment: Vundle doesn't do anything else than downloading, installing and managing the files from plugins, and adding them to the runtimepath. In other words; Vundle can't make a plugin not work.

Comment: @user2384250 is there a plugin that you found that does not work with Vundle? (also why is this question tagged with pathogen?)

Comment: @timss as far as I can tell the "Installation" for Vundle is the equivalent of "downloading with git" for the humans, so it's not exactly an installation.

Comment: @FDinoff this one https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete

Answer (score 2):

Plugins are generally not designed for use with a specific plugin manager. They all use more or less the same mechanisms and standardized file structure and should work the same way whether they are installed manually or "managed" with Vundle, Pathogen or some other script.

You should read Vundle's and your non-working plugin's documentation to see if you can find the why and how of your issue.

Also, what plugins do you have issues with? How did you install them? Are you asking a question with the hope of getting help or just thinking out loud?

Comment: "Are you asking a question or just thinking out loud?" – Beautiful. Just a normal day on Stackoverflow, I suppose.

Comment: this one doesn't work for me https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete , but it works flawlessy without Vundle or Pathogen, I also can't see the "standard" because I run into plugins that are using configure scripts, make, cmake, or vim-ball-archives, even more there are some of them with a cryptic and old fashion way of setting up variables and values that are essential for their own activity. I also think that the question is pretty clear and I'm not asking for any kind of help, but just clarifications about a specific software component.

Comment: The installation part ("configure scripts, make, cmake, or vim-ball-archives") doesn't matter. What matters, and is followed by most if not every plugin, is what to put where: there is a generic file structure with `autoload`, `plugin` and so on… how the individual parts ended up where they are is not important. If you have a problem with a specific problem, why don't you simply use that plugin's issue tracker? Open ended questions like this are more suited to r/vim.

Comment: Also, that plugin obviously needs its core components to be built with `make` so yeah, just pulling it with vundle won't do it. What made you think that Vundle and Git were the silver bullet that would solve all your plugin-related issues?

Comment: @romainl You don't have to compile it yourself, note the `Alternatively, you can also put the files in ~/.vim/`. Using Vundle, I've installed clang_complete on a multitude of computers, and I never had to do anything else than just adding it as a `Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'`.

Comment: @user2384250 How did you install it? Did you add it as a Bundle to your `.vimrc`, or use the interactive installer (i.e. `:BundleSearch` etc)?

Comment: @timss I have added that `Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'` in my `vimrc` but when I do `BundleInstall` from vim it simply downloads the branch at the HEAD, like you do with a pull, and nothing works, even if I go in the clang_complete folder under `~/.vim/bundle/` and compile from source, I can't find a way to make this plugin work under Vundle ...

Comment: @user2384250 Does it show up in `:BundleList`? Does it show any errors when downloaded (it'll show in the bottom on of the Vundle-window)? If the answer is "yes" and "no", respectively, I'm with romainl and suggest that you head over to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues) of clang_complete. If you do, please link the issue here and post the answer if there is one. And remember to check if it's been asked before :-) I've never had any problems installing clang_complete, only that it broke with lambdas on llvm 3.1.

Comment: Could you define "nothing works"? I just cloned that plugin in my bundle directory and it works as advertised. I use pathogen, though.